# How do I convert a string containing a simple math expression into a integer?

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

This code gives me the expected output just fine:

1

```py
>>> lista = ["8", "6"]
>>> lista = map(int, lista)
>>> print(list(lista))
'[8, 6]'
```

2

```py
>>> lista = [8-2, 6-2]
>>> print(list(lista))
'[6, 4]'
```

But if I do something like this it doesn't work:

```py
>>> lista = ["8-2", "6-2"]
>>> lista = map(int, lista)
>>> print(list(lista))

'print(list(lista))
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '8-2''
```

Why is that?
In my head it would go just like the 2º code :(
like this:

```py
>>> lista = ["8-2", "6-2"]
>>> lista = map(int, lista)
>>> print(list(lista))
'[6,4]'
#not a real situation
```

I'm a beginner!!! What should I do to have the expected output?
(sorry for bad English)

Comment: You need to parse the string expressions and perform the calculations in order to get the expected result. `8-2` is completely different from `"8-2"`. The former is an expression which consists of two integers and a binary operator on them, while the latter is a string literal.

Comment: You could look at this page for more information about Python Data Types:(https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datatypes.asp )